# How to get one line from a subprocess.call in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to pull one line from a subprocess.call but so far I'm having no luck. I want to do this with a number of different subprocess.calls but here is one for example:

```
output = subprocess.call('vmstat -s, shell=True)
```

The vmstat -s simple returns a list of current memory status. I could like to read say line 2 (used memory) and store it in a variable for later use.

What is the best way to go about this in python?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Use `check_output` instead of `call`:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output('vmstat -s', shell=True).splitlines()
```

alternatively you can pipe `stdout`:

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> for line in Popen('vmstat -s', shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout:
...     print(line)
... 
b'      3717436 K total memory\n'
b'      2151640 K used memory\n'
b'      1450432 K active memory\n'
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to read from a subprocess stdout is with the [communicate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) method.

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> proc = Popen(['vmstat', '-s'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
>>> stdout, _stderr = proc.communicate()
>>> stdout.splitlines()[1]
'     13278652 K used memory'
```

Note that using `shell=True` isn't needed here, and its use is generally discouraged when not required (there is unnecessary overhead, and it can create a shell injection security vulnerability in certain situations).